# Return with extra field from its relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

In my system, when a user sends a message, it creates a task at the same time. The task description is the body of the message.

There is a one-to-one relationship between task and message.

`Task.php`

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function message()
    {
        // one-to-one hasOne belongsTo
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Message'); // CAN NEVER be null, it MUST have an associated message
    }
```

When I fetch the task at my api.php endpoint of `/api/tasks/{task}` it calls `TaskController@show` which is this:

```
public function show(Task $task)
{
    return $task->with([
        'moments',
        'message.body as descript' <<<<<<< psuedo-code
    ]);
}
```

I have simplified this example. So this is not totally my real case, as in the above I might as well return the message. My real return is this:

```
public function show(Pet $pet)
{
    return $pet->load([
        'users',
        'tasks' => function($query) {
            $query->with([
                'moments',
                'upcomingAction',
                'message.body as descript' <<<<<<<<<< pseudo-code
            ]);
        }
    ]);
}
```

Is it possible to add an extra field "descript" to the returned Task?

Sincerest thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append new attribute to Task model [append in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

```
protected $appends='descript';

public function getDescriptAttribute()
{
    return 'something';

   //you have access to other attributes via $this->attributes['name']
}
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you Mahdi! This worked. There was one issue, I was getting error `array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given` but thanks so much for the docs link, it told me I needed to turn `protected $appends = ['descript'];`. An array. Thank you so much!

Comment: oh shoot I just found an issue. Because in my `getDescriptAttribute()` I am doing `$this->message->body` it is adding in the message into the json. I tried `makeHidden` but it give error. Here is my code - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/d7bf5296dcff89945db473ab132c0ece - and the error given is `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::makeHidden()` do you know how to hide this eager loaded relation?